# how to make a label always on top of animation

Tags: ios, animation, label

i am displaying an animation in my ViewController. and the animation images are an array of images.  when i start the animation, the images will cover one label i put on the ViewController. what can i do to keep the label on top of the images during the animation?
Below is my animation code;

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 325, 290);
NSMutableArray *animationImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"radar0%d.png",i+1];
    UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    [animationImageArray addObject:animationImage];
}
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
animationImageView.animationImages = animationImageArray;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 3;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[animationImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the UILabel to the UIApplication's keyWindow, rather than to the controller's view:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[keyWindow addSubview:myLabel];
```

Alternatively, you can bring your label to the front of the view after adding the animated `UIImageView`:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myLabel];
```

Comment: I added the first method in my viewDidLoad, but it does not work. however the second method works, thanks XD

Comment: For the first method to work you have to add it to ViewDidAppear not viewDidLoad